# How to upload data from my personal weather station?

Tags: upload, weather-api, wunderground

How can I contribute and UPLOAD PWS data to wunderground.com? Is there an API documentation available out there?

I found an API showing how to RETRIEVE data from the PWSs:

https://weather.com/swagger-docs/call-for-code

```
curl -X GET "https://api.weather.com/v2/pws/observations/current?stationId=KMAHANOV10&format=json&units=m&apiKey=adsf" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
```

From asking Dr Google I also found:

https://weatherstation.wunderground.com/weatherstation/updateweatherstation.php?QUERY_PARAMS

Is that the place to make data available? But where is an API doc available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://feedback.weather.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2924682-pws-upload-protocol?b_id=17298 - important is the parameter b_id, thanks to Google having it in the index.